# Is every $C_0$ semigroup on a Hilbert space automatically a $C_0$ group on a larger space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, semigroups-of-operators

Let $\{T(t),t\ge 0\}$ be a $C_0$ semigroup on a Hilbert space $X$, does that exist a larger Hilbert space $Y$ such that $X\subset Y$, and $T(t)$ extend to a  $C_0$ group $T'(t)$ (so $t<0$ make sense now) on $Y$?

**Edit:** Here "extend" means that $(T(t)x, y)=(T'(t)x, y)$ for all $x, y\in X$, which is weaker than its usual meaning. If the semigroup $T(t)$ is a contraction, then the conclusion is true, see Theorem 8.1 (p.29) in "Harmonic analysis of operators on Hilbert spaces" written by  Sz. Nagy, C. Foias,  H. Bercovici and L. Kérchy.

Comment: For something like the heat semigroup on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, it's difficult to imagine what that would look like.

Comment: More specifically, $e^{\Delta}$, say, has an unbounded inverse on $X=L^2$, and making the Hilbert space larger cannot fix this.

Comment: There are well known examples of semigroups for which T(t) is not injective for sufficiently large t. Clearly such a semigroup cannot be extended to a group on any space.

Comment: @NateEldredge , I also feel hard to believe at the beginning. But if the semigroup is a contraction (e.g. the heat semigroup), then there do exist such an "extension", see Thm 8.1 in the book I mentioned above

Comment: @MichaelRenardy, can you point out any reference of this result?Thanks.

Comment: I cannot read @MichaelRenardy's mind. But for example you can consider for $T$ the nilpotent left-shift on $X=L^2(0,1)$. Then $T(t)=0$ for all $t\geq 1$, and you cannot extend this to a group in the ordinary way. However, in this example the left-shift on $Y=L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is indeed an extension of $T$ in the sense you defined in your edit.

Comment: I think this can only be true if $X$ is closed in $Y$, and even in that case it is not clear to me. By the way, if $(T(t)x,y)=(T′(t)x,y)$ holds for all $y\in X$, doesn't this imply already that $T(t)x=T'(t)x$?

Comment: @gsa: Your example is illuminating, but can one think of a "natural" extension of the Gaussian semigroup, which is contractive, that makes it a group?

Answer (score 5):

An operator $A$ is a group generator if and only if both $A$ and $-A$ are semigroup generators. So under your assumptions, if we denote by $\tilde{A}$ the generator of the extension $\{\tilde{T}(t),t\ge 0\}$ of $\{T(t),t\ge 0\}$ to $Y$, then $-\tilde{A}$ would be a semigroup generator, too.

If by "extend" you mean the usual thing (viz, that $X$ is left invariant under $\{\tilde{T}(t),t\ge 0\}$ and the restriction to $X$ of $\{\tilde{T}(t),t\ge 0\}$ is $\{T(t),t\ge 0\}$ again), then $X$ would be left invariant under $\{T(t),t\le 0\}$, too, and the generator of this semigroup would necessarily be the part in $X$ of $-\tilde{A}$. So, the analytic semigroup $\{T(t),t\ge 0\}$ would actually imbed into a group $\{T(t),t\in \mathbb R\}$ on $X$ as well.

Now, an analytic semigroup on a Banach space $X$ can imbed into a group if and only if <strike>$X$ is finite dimensional</strike> its generator is bounded.

Comment: I guess I'm misinterpreting something, but your last claim puzzles me: why doesn't the semigroup $e^{it\Delta}$, $t\ge 0$, on $L^2$ embed in the group $e^{it\Delta}$, $t\in\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that can be what you mean.  More simply, what about the semigroup $T(t) x = e^{t} x$, whose generator is $I$?  That's an analytic semigroup that embeds in a group, no matter what $X$ is.

Comment: @NateEldredge: You are right, I have edited.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: But $e^{it\Delta}$ is not analytic!

Comment: Thanks, here, "extend" is a little bit weaker than the usual meaning, see my edit above. I'm curious to know that if this also implies that the generator of  the "smaller" semigroup is part of $-\tilde{A}$.